# IO Completion Ports vs. Thread Pool API

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, threadpool

I had a problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258283/waiting-win32-threads), and I was suggested to use IO completion ports or thread pool.

I have implemented IO completion, calling `PostQueuedCompletionStatus` to enqueue the task and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` to get the next task to execute it. I am using IO completion port as a multi-producer/multi-consumer thread-safe FIFO container without explicit locks. This makes me have full control over the threads, because I may need to terminate the ones process for a long time and report them. Also `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` waits the calling thread if there is no task left.

Aside from the termination, thread pool suits my needs: my tasks are completed less than a millisecond, but there are lots of them. Also calling `QueueUserWorkItem` and letting the OS do the synchronizations and executions is simpler.

Are there any differences between two approaches performance-wise? Any comments about my implementation?

Comment: um. IO Completion Ports ARE a thread pooling mechanism. and, if you are using a different thread pool API, are probably the underlying mechanism used by the API.

Comment: @Chris Becke: By thread pool, I mean calling QueueUserWorkItem to enqueue the tasks.

Comment: I read the question you linked to, and have you considered the Visual Studio 2010 Concurrency Runtime?

Comment: @DeadMG: Not Visual Studio 2010 Concurrency Runtime but the thread pool API. But if there is not much difference I will not change my implementation. It is already too much complicated. And there is a thread termination problem. Termination is not suggested, because of stack leaks anyhow but, in thread pooling there may be even greater isuues. With io completion port you are free with the threads, because you are managing them.

Comment: You're not doing anything with IO so why use IO Completion Port at all? If you want full control over threads, then create your own thread pool (use WaitForMultipleObjects etc. to wait and signal for task).

Comment: @ZachSaw The purpose of *creating* a Completion Port is because it **is** the mechanism used to implement a thread pool. The Windows thread pools call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, and blocking call that will return when there is work to be done. Windows will assign the work to *one* of the threads that are sitting idle in `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` in order to give them the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completion Ports are designed to avoid unnecessary context switching. When your thread that is calling GetQueuedCompletionStatus is done processing a work item, it can call right back to GetQueuedCompletionStatus to continue to get more work within its current CPU timeslice.

@Jonathan - If you have blocking calls, then those should pretty much *never* be made on a thread pulling work items. They should either be performed async (with a Begin/End or *Async call) or block on another thread (worker thread pool). This will ensure that all of your threads servicing the completion port are actually doing work instead of wasting time blocking when other work items are available.

A slight clarification: if you are managing your own threads and calling GetQueuedCompletionStatus, then you have created your own completion port separate from the IO completion port and associated thread pool used by the OS for async IO calls.

Comment: Yes, in a while loop a thread calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`, gets the task, completes it. It is very efficient. IO completion port nearly works with 5 threads out of 10 for millions of tasks with ~0% CPU load. The far most useful API I have ever used.

Answer (score 2):

IO Completion Port (IOCP) is typically used with a threadpool to handle IO events/activities while the WinAPI threadpool (which you indicate via QueueUserWorkItem) is merely Microsoft's implementation of a typical threadpool that will handle non-IO tasks.

Looking at your linked thread, it looks like you're simply dequeing a task from a FIFO list which has nothing to do with IO. So, the latter is most likely what you are after. I don't think performance difference should be your concern here as opposed to which is the right API for what you're doing.

EDIT: If you need full control over thread creation and termination (although it's never OK to terminate a thread as the stack will not unwind), then you'll be better off creating your own threadpool by using WaitForSingleObject (or rather MultipleObjects for exit signal as well) and SetEvent. WinAPI's threadpool is basically Microsoft's automatic thread creation and termination depending on the load of the threads.

Comment: First of all, I prefer to rely on well tested, documented, engineered (I hope so:) ) OS specific API. Second custom threadpool implementation is a very very hard one. Besides, with all the events, semaphores or even critical sections, explicit locking will make your implementation work slow. Less locks, thread switches will lead more efficiency IMHO. All those APIs manages these things.

Comment: @sad_man: Not true. A threadpool is extremely easy. Create 10 threads, wait on WaitForSingleObject, and Signal task with SetEVent. That's a threadpool. WinAPI threadpool requires you to do the same sync and locks if your design mandates it. Don't for one second think the OS handles those for ya.

Comment: @sad_man: Like I said in my reply, if you need full control, then the only way is to create your own threadpool. If you wish to rely on WinAPI threadpool, you'll have to put up with its design and implementation.

Comment: WaitForSingleObject and all those I mentioned were WinAPI - they're as reliable as WinAPI goes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IO completion ports, and create your own X threads which call GetQueuedCompletionStatus(), and you have X tasks that takes a long time (say, read from network), then all threads would be busy and further requests will starve. AFAIU, thread pool will spin another thread in this case.

Also, never use TerminateThread()! When allocating memory from the heap, a thread temporarily acquire that heap's CRITICAL_SECTION. So if a thread is terminated in the middle of this, other threads trying to allocate from the same heap will hang. And, there's no way for you to know whether the thread is allocating or not.

Comment: Actually my tasks do not take long time, but in my app users can write their proprietary codes and my concern is what if user's code enter in an endless loop or a loop that takes a very long time to exit. I can not risk the other working codes. So some how I need to force that thread to end. 
Can you give any material about threads acquiring heap's CRITICAL_SECTION?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between QueueUserWorkItem and IOCompletionPorts is QueueUserWorkItem is an easy to use higher level abstraction.
Its easy to see how QueueUserWorkItem could be implemented on top of IOCompletionPorts (I don't know that it is).

The practical difference is - QueueUserWorkItem creates (and manages) threads in the thread pool. As such, it doesn;t know up front how many threads it will need: It starts with a few( perhaps just one) and then creates additional pool threads at intervals if the thread pool has no free threads to handle queued items.

This means that using QueueUserWorkItem can result in a significant delay to process items if many items are added while the pool is small, consequently, bursts of items being added can cause the pool to grow larger than it needs to.