# Multithreading program

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

basically my program has 2 sets of threads, workers and jobs. Each job has an arrival time, then it is pushed onto a queue.

For the servers, I want them to constantly look for a job on the queue, once there is a job on the queue, only 1 worker takes it off and does its thing with it.

In main, all the worker threads are created first and then the job threads are created and synchronized (each pushing stuff on the queue). I can't get the timing right as the worker threads sometimes do things at exactly the same time OR the jobs aren't being pushed onto the queue at the right times (ie. job with arrival time 3 is pushed before job with arrival time 2).
How can I do this using semaphores and/or mutexes?

I tried to put a mutex in the worker function but I don't really have a good handle on mutexes/semaphores..

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your terminology is painful.  Rewrite this with server = worker, client = job, client thread = server.

Comment: Ugh. Except for using `std::cout`, this is pure C code. Are you aware that C++ is a lot more than just a C add-on? If you're so fond of C, that you even use the `struct` keyword where C++ doesn't require it, but C does, then why not abandon streams in favor of `printf()` etc. and do pure C? As it is you make the C crowd unhappy for using streams, and the C++ crowd for using C except for the streams.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258283/waiting-win32-threads/4258377#4258377) to [one of my earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258283/waiting-win32-threads/). My question concerns Win32 threads but the described consept pretty much the same with pthreads.

1. Use a semaphore in your queue to indicate whether there are elements ready to be processed.
2. Every time you add an item, call `sem_post()` to increment the count associated with the semaphore
3. In the loop in your thread process, call `sem_wait()` on the handle of your semaphore object

Here is a tutorial for [POSIX Semaphores](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html)

But first like the other guy said, you have to make Q thread-safe.

```
void *func(void *newWorker) {
    struct workerType* worker = (struct workerType*) newWorker;
    while(numServed < maxJobs) {
        //if(!Q.empty()) {
        // No need to ask if Q is empty.
        // If a thread passes the sem_wait function 
        // there has to be at least one job in the Q 
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        struct jobType* job = Q.front();
        numServed++;
        cout << job->jobNum << " was served by " << worker->workerNum << endl;
        Q.pop();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        //sleep(worker->runTime); No need to sleep also        
        //}
    }
}


void *job(void *jobdata) {
    struct jobType *job = (struct jobType*) jobdata;
    //sleep(job->arrivtime);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    Q.push(job);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&semaphore);
    // Inform the workers that another job is pushed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Would the initial semaphore value be 0?

Comment: @user623982: Yes, 0 would be fine. In this case the value of the semaphore is equal to the current number of jobs in the Q.

Comment: What if I need both functions to sleep? Jobs sleep their respective arrival times before being pushed onto the queue, workers sleep their run time after acquiring a job. I tried doing this several ways but I get incorrect results.

Comment: @user623982: Why do you want them to sleep? For synchronizing? It is useless. For one writer and one reader thread maybe, it depends on your implementation, you have to sleep one, long enough that the other does its thing. So you assume a number of milliseconds. Still not useful, and very very dangerous. You have multiple readers and writers. It will not work, that is why you get incorrect results. Use semaphore, it will take care of waiting the thread. Never ever assume anything when writing multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 1):

The Q push to Q pop operation needs to be atomic i.e (is the Critical section). Put that under a Mutex acquire and Mutex release. That should do it for you.

Check the posix thread tutorial to understand mutex acquisition and release. I use this  [PTHREAD TUTORIAL](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your servers are doing three non-atomic queue operations (empty, then front, then pop) with no synchronization to ensure that some other thread doesn't interleave its operations.  You need to acquire a mutex or semaphore before calling Q.empty and release it after calling Q.pop to ensure that the empty/front/pop trio is done atomically.  You also need to make sure you release the mutux properly if Q.empty fails